# Baily-Borel Compactification

Tags: reference-request

This is a reference request. I am new to this particular topic and the original paper is a bit difficult to read. I would be grateful if someone could provide a reference/examples where it has been worked out/expository set of notes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the following references.

1. Smooth Compactifications of Locally Symmetric Spaces - Ash, Mumford, Rapoport, Tai.
2. Espaces Hermitian Symmetriques - Deligne. There is a translation avaliable due to Milne on the webpage.
3. Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces - Helgason. Chapter 8 seems to be of some interest.

Any additions to the list are appreciated. Thanks.